# Excel: Count if value is present in 3 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

How do I count the number of values that are present across ALL THREE columns?

For example, “L160” is the only value that is in all 3 columns, so the formula should equal 1.

[Screenshot of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsOrA.jpg)

Comment: you just want to know if the value in the third column is present in the other two columns?  1 if its in each column at least once? and 0 if its not present in any of the columns?

Comment: What is the number supposed to be if its 3 times in the first column 2 in the second and 4 in the third?  1 still?

Comment: @ForwardEd, the number will not be present more than once in a column, as they represent people and are unique codes. Correct, it should just read 1 as long as the same code is seen in all 3 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula will check if the value in C is present at least once in A, at least once in B, and makes sure that the value in C is not blank.  If all three conditions are true it will return 1 and it fails it will return 0

```
=--AND(COUNTIF(A:A,C2)>=1,COUNTIF(B:B,C2)>=1,C2<>"")
```

Place the above formula in am empty cell and copy down as need be.

[image: POC]

Comment: Thank you, @ForwardEd, this seemed to have worked the best! I originally hoped that I wouldn't need a helper column to add this up, but it will work just fine! :) All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can start, using the `Match()` function: if the string is found, the location is shown. If not, you get an error message. This return value is checked, using an `If()` function: if the value is ok (larger than 0), the value 1 is returned, otherwise 0.

```
=IF(MATCH(C2;A$2:A$39;0)>0;1;0)
```

The result of this will either be 1 (C2 is present in column A) or #Error (I tried getting 0 but this failed, no problem however).

This you can do three times, and you add the results, something like:

```
=IF(MATCH(C2;A$2:A$39;0)>0;1;0)
+IF(MATCH(C2;B$2:B$39;0)>0;1;0)
+IF(MATCH(C2;C$2:C$5;0)>0;1;0)
```

You divide the result by three in order for the successful result being equal to 1.

On that, you apply an `IFERROR()` function, translating the errors into 0.

Off you go :-)

Comment: Just multiply three `ISNUMBER(MATCH())` to each other and you will get 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

If one has the new Dynamic Array formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,C:C<>"")),A:A,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,C:C<>"")),B:B,0)))
```

No helper columns needed.

[image]

Comment: The outstanding question is does the OP want the answer to be 1 or more in the scenario where there are multiple entries in a given column?